# How do I prevent my mobx store from resetting when switching routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, mobx, mobx-react

Im using mobx to hold my login state. After logging in, navigating to a new route with react router forces my store to reset and logs me out. What am I doing wrong?

https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-cache-k7c8c?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What happens if we also mark the bottom export default as an observer? I am using mobx as well, though I can't say I've ever faced those issues. Normally if I want to make some sort of function that affects a variable in my state I prefix it with @action

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Nav.Link` from `react-bootstrap`, but they act like regular `a` link tags, they reload whole page when clicked so everything gets cleaned up, reset.

What you need to do is use `Link` component from `react-router-dom` like that `<Link to="/">Home</Nav.Link>` (make sure to rename `href` prop to `to`). Then page won't be reloaded, instead browser history would be utilized.

Comment: This was it! Also found a nice library to help wrap the link so it looks like the bootstrap css. react-router-bootstrap